# printing a translation in google translate with selenium - python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to auto translate a word to English and I have figured out how to actually translate whatever word I type to English however I'm stuck onto actually getting that information and printing it.

2 examples of the  element

```html
<span jsaction="click:qtZ4nf,GFf3ac,tMZCfe; contextmenu:Nqw7Te,QP7LD; mouseout:Nqw7Te; mouseover:qtZ4nf,c2aHje" jsname="W297wb">Hello</span>

<span jsaction="click:qtZ4nf,GFf3ac,tMZCfe; contextmenu:Nqw7Te,QP7LD; mouseout:Nqw7Te; mouseover:qtZ4nf,c2aHje" jsname="W297wb">I like it</span>
```

I noticed that these have the same information except the translation so I was wondering if I needed to parse it somehow?

Comment: What information are you trying to get - "Hello" and "I like it"?

Comment: they are just 2 examples (hola for one search and then me gusta for the other)  im trying to get the english translation which is hello or I like it

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/j9ETE52.png this is what it all looks like if you need some more information.

Comment: You should be able to get the span's contents by selecting it and getting its `.text` attribute.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/o5I1xev.png sort of like that? I'm not fully sure on how to select it sorry.

Comment: See the documentation [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started_with_webdriver/locating_elements/), for example. You can use the Chrome Dev Tools to get the span's **full** CSS selector, then use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector()` to select it. `.text` should then work.

Comment: You may also want to try out the [`googletrans`](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) Python package. If it still works, it looks like it's pretty easy to use.

Comment: ok so the css selector is different for each search? for example #ow306 > div.J0lOec > span.VIiyi > span > span is one search and #ow306 > div.J0lOec > span.VIiyi > span > span  is the other search, im not sure on how to do this now /:

Comment: nvm i copied the full xpath and then searched the xpath instead and that works fine so far :) tysm for the help <3